# What is $∫_0^7 (x−5)^{\frac{-2}{3}}dx$?

Tags: integration

Find

$∫_0^7 (x−5)^{\frac{-2}{3}}dx$

where negative values are passed into a root function you should consider the Complex Conjugate Root Theorem and the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra to determine whether a real solution exists. If a real solution exists you must use this branch.

To me, it is like the following:

$\int_0^7 (x-5)^{\frac{-2}{3}}dx$ $=\frac{(x-2)^{{\frac{-2}{3}}+1}}{\frac{-2}{3}+1}\bigg|_0^7$

What is the info/instructions at the end doing here?

Comment: What branch are you using?

Comment: I am integral it as a real function.

Comment: No, I'm asking what branch you have in mind.

Comment: @user438666 Any nonzero real number can be raised to the $-2/3$ power, and the answer is a real number. This is true for any rational exponent with odd denominator.

Comment: @GregMartin My bad! I mistakenly read it as $-3/2$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's separate into two parts.  Then we can insert the OP's desired definition for negative number to the power $-2/3$.
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^7 (x-5)^{-2/3}\;dx
&=\int_{0}^5 (x-5)^{-2/3}\;dx+\int_{5}^7 (x-5)^{-2/3}\;dx
\\
&=\int_{0}^5 (5-x)^{-2/3}\;dx+\int_{5}^7 (x-5)^{-2/3}\;dx
\\
&=\big[-3(5-x)^{1/3}\big]_0^5 + \big[3(x-5)^{1/3}\big]_5^7
=3\cdot 5^{1/3} + 3\cdot 2^{1/3}
\end{align}
It turned out that our antiderivative
$$
\begin{cases}
-3(5-x)^{1/3},\quad x<5,
\\
+3(x-5)^{1/3},\quad\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
is continuous at $x=5$, so Ryan's computation without dividing the interval works out OK.  But I would do it this way anyway, just to be safe.

---

In order to use the fundamental theorem of calculus to evaluate an integral, we need to check that our antiderivative is continuous.  In this case, the integrand is undefined at $x=5$, so a check that $x=5$ is a removable discontinuity of the antiderivative should definitely be included.
Haven't we all seen the erroneous computation $$\int_{-1}^1\frac{dx}{x^2} = \Big[\frac{-1}{x}\Big]_{-1}^1 = -2$$

Answer (score -1):

I'd use a simple substitution to evaluate this definite integral.

$\int_0^7\left(x-5\right)^{-\frac{2}{3}}dx$

$y=x-5$

$dy=dx$

$\int_0^7\left(x-5\right)^{-\frac{2}{3}}dx\to\int_{-5}^2y^{-\frac{2}{3}}dy$

$=\left[3\sqrt[3]{y}\right]_{-5}^2$

$=3\sqrt[3]{2}+3\sqrt[3]{5}$

$\approx8.910$

Comment: Although the suggested substitution seems like the perfect way to do it, ignoring the "explosion" at $y=0$ is pretty bad practice. I'm afraid I have to give a down vote.